# How many numbers are there between $0$ and $1000$ which on division by $2, 4, 6, 8$ leave remainders $1, 3, 5, 7$ resp?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How many numbers are there between $0$ and $1000$ which on division by $2, 4, 6, 8$ leave remainders $1, 3, 5, 7$ resp?

What I did:-
Observe the difference between divisor and remainder. $2-1=1$
$4-3=1$
$LCM(2,4,6,8)=24K-1$
Between $0$ and $1000$ there are $1001$ numbers
$n=24K-1$
$1001=24K-1$
$1002=24K$
But in the solution it has been given
$1000=24K-1$

Comment: Every such number $n$ corresponds to a number $n+1$ in $\{1,\dots,1001\}$ which is divisible by all of $2,4,6,8$.

Answer (score 4):

You want the number of $n$ between $0$ and $1000$ such that $n \equiv -1 \mod 24$.  $1000 = 41 \times 24 + 16$, so there is one of these in each of the $41$ intervals
$[0, 23],\; [1 \cdot 24, 1 \cdot 24 + 23],\; \ldots [40 \cdot 24, 40 \cdot 24 + 23]$ where $40 \cdot 24 + 23 =  983$.  The next one would be $982+24 = 1006$, which is too big.  So the answer  is $41$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be all of the numbers that could happen. We get that $x \equiv 23 \pmod {24}$.

As $1000$ is not congruent to $23 \pmod {24}$, in total, this gives us $\lfloor\frac{1000}{24}\rfloor$ possibilities, which gives us the answer of $41$.